# problems with close session in shiny and cleaned temp files

Tags: r, shiny

I'am new in shiny, i've created an app with user interaction, they can upload theirs files for processing.
All is ok for visualizing and creating graphs, but my problems is: Why i can create a function for delete the uploaded files when the session close?

I tried with these lines of code: (inside of server function)

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
   if (!is.null(input$file1)) {
file.remove(input$file1$datapath)
  }
})
```

and :

```
onStop(function() {
   if (!is.null(input$file1)) {
file.remove(input$file1$datapath) }
})
```

with this error message:

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation 
not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do 
something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or 
observer.)
  41: stop
  40: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
  39: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
  38: $.reactivevalues
```

I really appreciated all type of help
thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe `if(!is.null(isolate(input$file1)))` and `file.remove(isolate(input$file1$datapath))`.

Comment: doesn't work for me ... but thank for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow!

`input` variable can only by accessed from a reactive context, hence the error. A reactive context is any `render`, `observe`, `reactive`, `observeEvent` or `eventReactive` call.

Furthermore, temp files are automatically deleted on session end. Here is a slightly modified example from https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),

      # Input: Select quotes ----
      radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                   choices = c(None = "",
                               "Double Quote" = '"',
                               "Single Quote" = "'"),
                   selected = '"'),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")

    )

  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    # when reading semicolon separated files,
    # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
    tryCatch(
      {
        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                       header = input$header,
                       sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote)

        cat(input$file1$datapath)
      },
      error = function(e) {
        # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
        stop(safeError(e))
      }
    )

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Run the app, and while it is running flow the temp file path in the console. Once you close the app and the session ends try to follow the path again and it would be deleted.

Comment: thanks @Sada93 for your help, your explanation of the problem for input and reactive values was very useful... thank to your code i understood better how i can remove the temp files. Finally i used this line of code for solve my problem:  `session$onSessionEnded(function() { file.remove(file.path(dir(pattern = ".csv"))) })`

Comment: @LuisCano but shiny removes the file automatically. If you want to force the director to be removed you can access the temporary directory with `tempdir()`